# Conditional Intersections in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr, intersection

Looking to filter out animals which are in both tables (intersect condition 1) and share the same size within same category across tables (intersect condition 2). Know an efficient way to code this -- e.g., with dplyr?

```
library(dplyr)
animal1 <- data.frame(type = c("cat", "dog", "dog","bird", "elephant"), 
                      size = c("small","large","small", "medium", "large"), tableName = rep("animal1",5), stringsAsFactors = F)
      #       type   size tableName
      # 1      cat  small   animal1
      # 2      dog  large   animal1
      # 3      dog  small   animal1
      # 4     bird  medium   animal1
      # 5 elephant  large   animal1

animal2 <- data.frame(type = c("elephant", "dog", "dog", "elephant", "elephant"), 
                      size = c("medium","large","large", "small", "large"), 
                      tableName = rep("animal2",5), stringsAsFactors = F)
      #      type   size tableName
      # 1 elephant medium   animal2
      # 2      dog  large   animal2
      # 3      dog  large   animal2
      # 4 elephant  small   animal2
      # 5 elephant  large   animal2


rbindAnimal <- rbind(animal1, animal2)
      #        type   size tableName
      # 1       cat  small   animal1
      # 2       dog  large   animal1
      # 3       dog  small   animal1
      # 4      bird medium   animal1
      # 5  elephant  large   animal1
      # 6  elephant medium   animal2
      # 7       dog  large   animal2
      # 8       dog  large   animal2
      # 9  elephant  small   animal2
      # 10 elephant  large   animal2

# Intersection across both tables
intersectType <- intersect( rbindAnimal %>% filter(tableName == "animal1") %>% select(type), 
                                          rbindAnimal %>% filter(tableName == "animal2") %>% select(type) ) 
      #     type
      # 1 elephant
      # 2      dog

rbindAnimal <- rbindAnimal[which(rbindAnimal$type %in% intersectType$type),]

      #        type   size tableName
      # 2       dog  large   animal1
      # 3       dog  small   animal1
      # 5  elephant  large   animal1
      # 6  elephant medium   animal2
      # 7       dog  large   animal2
      # 8       dog  large   animal2
      # 9  elephant  small   animal2
      # 10 elephant  large   animal2

# Needs to return row numbers! Here: 2,5,7,8, and 10
#        type   size tableName
# 2       dog  large   animal1
# 5  elephant  large   animal1
# 7       dog  large   animal2
# 8       dog  large   animal2
# 10 elephant  large   animal2
```

Comment: The desired output is not clear. are you trying to merge on type and size, or trying to keep only type-size observations that are not present in both data.frames?

Comment: Good point! I think merging by type and size is what I'm aiming at. The last lines show the desired output -- where row index values can allow for reverse filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Needs to return row numbers!"

This is pretty straightforward using `.I` from data.table, which stores row numbers:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(rbindAnimal)

w <- rbindAnimal[, if (uniqueN(tableName) > 1L) .I, by=.(type, size)]$V1
# [1]  2  7  8  5 10
rbindAnimal[-w]
#        type   size tableName
# 1:      cat  small   animal1
# 2:      dog  small   animal1
# 3:     bird medium   animal1
# 4: elephant medium   animal2
# 5: elephant  small   animal2
```

Instead of an anti-join (like the OP's answer), we're just excluding rows by number.

*How it works*

- `uniqueN` counts the number of unique values. The OP's condition is (paraphrasing):

  > The type-size combo appears in both tables.

  which translates to

  > `uniqueN(tableName) > 1L` in the `by=.(type, size)` group of rows.
- `if (cond) x` gives `x` if the condition holds; and `NULL` otherwise, dropping the group.

---

*dplyr variant*

It works fine in dplyr as well (though I'm not sure how to get row numbers):

```
rbindAnimal %>% group_by(type, size) %>% filter(n_distinct(tableName) == 1L)
#       type   size tableName
#      <chr>  <chr>     <chr>
# 1      cat  small   animal1
# 2      dog  small   animal1
# 3     bird medium   animal1
# 4 elephant medium   animal2
# 5 elephant  small   animal2
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: using merge / semi_join / anti_join (thanks for the merge tip @Imo !)

```
library(dplyr)
animal1 <- data.frame(type = c("cat", "dog", "dog","bird", "elephant"), 
                      size = c("small","large","small", "medium", "large"), tableName = rep("animal1",5), stringsAsFactors = F)
      #       type   size tableName
      # 1      cat  small   animal1
      # 2      dog  large   animal1
      # 3      dog  small   animal1
      # 4     bird  medium   animal1
      # 5 elephant  large   animal1

animal2 <- data.frame(type = c("elephant", "dog", "dog", "elephant", "elephant"), 
                      size = c("medium","large","large", "small", "large"), 
                      tableName = rep("animal2",5), stringsAsFactors = F)
      #      type   size tableName
      # 1 elephant medium   animal2
      # 2      dog  large   animal2
      # 3      dog  large   animal2
      # 4 elephant  small   animal2
      # 5 elephant  large   animal2

rbindAnimal <- rbind(animal1, animal2)
mergedAnimals <- merge(animal1, animal2, by = c("type","size"), all = T)
sharedTypeSize <- mergedAnimals[complete.cases(mergedAnimals),] %>% select(type,size) %>% unique
sharedTypeSize <- merge(rbindAnimal, sharedTypeSize)

semi_join(rbindAnimal, sharedTypeSize)
      #        type  size tableName
      # 1      dog large   animal1
      # 2      dog large   animal2
      # 3      dog large   animal2
      # 4 elephant large   animal1
      # 5 elephant large   animal2

anti_join(rbindAnimal, sharedTypeSize)

      #       type   size tableName
      # 1      cat  small   animal1
      # 2      dog  small   animal1
      # 3     bird medium   animal1
      # 4 elephant medium   animal2
      # 5 elephant  small   animal2
```